# Mootools get bottom dropdaownlist dynamically

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am new to javascript and MooTools. And I need to get the bottom dropdownlist on a page.
The top and bottom dropdownlist, is to set the number of items per page.
The bottom dropdown lists id is dynamic and changes according hvord many elements that are at hand.

I have searched the Internet but have not found it. So if one of you could give me an example.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please supply some code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean with 'top' and 'bottom', but assuming you mean their place in the DOM, you could do something like this:

```
var dropdowns = $$('select');
var firstDropdown = dropdowns[0];
var lastDropdown = dropdowns.getLast();
```

This would select all the `<select>` elements on the page, regardless of their identifiers.

Comment: Thanks, that is a simple and easy solution.